# Python optimization algorithm to maximize the ellipse inside arbitrary polygon

Tags: python, optimization, convex

I'm trying to make biggest ellipse inside arbitrary polygon.

So, I made the equation of ellipse and constraint .

```
objective : minimize A*B   (mimimaze 1/area) 

 st. A**2*(x-x0)**2+B**2*(y-y0)**2 = 0 
     x/100.0  + y/80.0 < 1
     x/-20.0  + y/80.0 < 1
     x/-40.0  + y/-40.0 > 1
     x/100.0  + y/-60.0 > 1
```

then I made optimization code using Scipy like below 
But my code makes False result. (Success : False). 
Can you explain why my code cannot make successful result? due to false constraint? wrong coding? Note that I don't need tilted ellipse.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
def objective(C):
    A = C[0] ; B = C[1] ; x0 = C[2] ; y0 = C[3] ; x  = C[4] ; y  = C[5]    
    return A*B

def constraint1(C):   
    A = C[0] ; B = C[1] ; x0 = C[2] ; y0 = C[3] ; x  = C[4] ; y  = C[5]   
    return (x/100.0+y/80.0-1)*-1

def constraint2(C):
    A = C[0] ; B = C[1] ; x0 = C[2] ; y0 = C[3] ; x  = C[4] ; y  = C[5]   
    return (x/-100.0+y/80.0-1)*-1

def constraint3(C):
    A = C[0] ; B = C[1] ; x0 = C[2] ; y0 = C[3] ; x  = C[4] ; y  = C[5]   
    return (x/-100.0+y/-80.0-1)*-1

def constraint4(C):
    A = C[0] ; B = C[1] ; x0 = C[2] ; y0 = C[3] ; x  = C[4] ; y  = C[5]   
    return (x/100.0+y/-80.0-1)*-1

def constraint5(C):
    A = C[0] ; B = C[1] ; x0 = C[2] ; y0 = C[3] ; x  = C[4] ; y  = C[5]    
    return A**2*(x-x0)**2+B**2*(y-y0)**2-1

xeval = [1,1,0,0,0,0]
bnds = (  (0.001,1),(0.001,1),(-100,100),(-100,100),(-500,500),(-500,500)  )


con1 = {'type': 'ineq','fun':constraint1}
con2 = {'type': 'ineq' , 'fun':constraint2}
con3 = {'type': 'ineq','fun':constraint3}
con4 = {'type': 'ineq' , 'fun':constraint4}
con5 = {'type': 'eq' , 'fun':constraint5}
cons = [con1,con2,con3,con4,con5]  
sol = minimize(objective,xeval,method='SLSQP',bounds=bnds,constraints=cons)
```

Comment: Edit your question to include a question. "Doesn't work" is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

I made poor answer for some arbitrary polygon. I found using convex optimization might be bad for non-ideal polygon. I made this application to calculate lithography pw window. I hope someone make better solution. 
[image]

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Apr 14 00:20:43 2018

@author: hafss
"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import numpy as np 


step = 0.3
px_old = [1,8,11,20,25,40, 30,5 ,2 ,1,1 ]
py_old = [1,2,5, 4 ,2, 8 , 15,14,11,5,1 ]
init_point = [5,4]
init_radius = step


px = []
py = []
for i in range(len(px_old)-1):
    dx = px_old[i+1]-px_old[i]
    dy = py_old[i+1]-py_old[i]
    len1 = (dx*dx+dy*dy)**0.5
    px.append(px_old[i])
    py.append(py_old[i])

    if len1 > step:
        count = int(len1/step)
        for ii in range(count):
            #print px_old[i]+ 1.0*ii/count*dx
            #print py_old[i]+ 1.0*ii/count*dy
            px.append(px_old[i]+ 1.0*ii/count*dx    )
            py.append(py_old[i]+ 1.0*ii/count*dy    )
px.append(px_old[-1])
py.append(py_old[-1])
plt.figure()
plt.plot(px,py,color='r')
#plt.plot(px_old,py_old,)
ax = plt.gca()
minrr = 6
def check_inner(poly_x,poly_y,a,b,x0,y0 ):
    minrr = 5
    for i in range(len(poly_x)):
        x=poly_x[i]
        y=poly_y[i]        
        rr = ((x-x0)/a)**2+((y-y0)/b)**2
        if rr < minrr:
            minrr = rr
        #if rr < 1 : 
        #    badpoint.append([x,y])
    return minrr 
def draw_ellips(handle,xc,yc,a,b,color,lw):
    ellipse = Ellipse(xy=(xc, yc), width=a*2, height=b*2, 
                        edgecolor=color, fc='None', lw=lw)
    handle.add_patch(ellipse)     
def get_jumperpoint(poly_x,poly_y,sizeup,a,b,x0,y0   ):
    badx = []
    bady = []
    for i in range(len(poly_x)):
        x=poly_x[i]
        y=poly_y[i]        
        rr = ((x-x0)/(a+sizeup))**2+((y-y0)/(b+sizeup))**2
        if rr < 1 :
            badx.append(x)
            bady.append(y)
    xmean = np.asarray(badx).mean()
    ymean = np.asarray(bady).mean()   
    xmove = x0-xmean
    ymove = y0-ymean
    return [xmove,ymove]
rx = init_radius
ry = init_radius
xc = init_point[0]
yc = init_point[1]
maxarea = step*step
for iterat in range(90):
    print "iterate start %s (%s,%s)->(%s,%s)" % (iterat,xc,yc,rx,ry)
    s1 = step
    s2 = step
    s3 = step
    draw_ellips(ax,xc,yc,rx,ry,'blue',0.5)

    rxprev = rx 
    ryprev = ry
    xcprev = xc
    ycprev = yc
    if check_inner(px,py,rx+s1,ry+s2,xc,yc) >= 1 : 
        rx = rx+s1
        ry = ry+s2

    # enlarge
    if check_inner(px,py,rx+s1,ry,xc,yc) >= 1 : 
        rx = rx+s1

    if check_inner(px,py,rx,ry+s1,xc,yc) >= 1 : 
        ry = ry+s1

    #distortion
    if check_inner(px,py,rx+s1,ry-s2,xc,yc) >= 1 and (rx+s1)*(ry-s2) > rx*ry : 
        rx = rx+s1
        ry = ry-s2      

    if check_inner(px,py,rx-s1,ry+s2,xc,yc) >= 1 and (rx-s1)*(ry+s2) > rx*ry : 
        rx = rx-s1
        ry = ry+s2 
    #shift @ enlarge (right dir )
    if check_inner(px,py,rx+s1,ry,xc+s2,yc) >= 1 : 
        rx = rx+s1
        xc = xc+s2

    if check_inner(px,py,rx+s1,ry,xc-s2,yc) >= 1 : 
        rx = rx+s1
        xc = xc-s2      

    if check_inner(px,py,rx,ry+s1,xc,yc+s2) >= 1 : 
        ry = ry+s1
        yc = yc+s2

    if check_inner(px,py,rx,ry+s1,xc,yc-s2) >= 1 : 
        ry = ry+s1
        yc = yc-s2      

    if check_inner(px,py,rx,ry,xc,yc) < 1 : 
        rx = rx-2*step-0.001
        ry = ry-2*step-0.001
        if rx < 0.001 : rx = 0.001
        if ry < 0.001 : ry = 0.001
        print "reduce"

    print "iterate end   %s (%s,%s)->(%s,%s) best %s " % (iterat,xc,yc,rx,ry,maxarea)        
    if rx == rxprev and ry == ryprev and xcprev == xc and ycprev== yc  and check_inner(px,py,rx,ry,xc,yc) >= 1 : 
        [jx,jy] = get_jumperpoint(px,py,step*5,rx,ry,xc,yc   )
        print "jump %s %s -> %s %s" % (xc,yc,xc+jx,yc+jy)
        xc = xc+jx
        yc = yc+jy     

    if rx*ry > maxarea    :
        bestiter = iterat
        bestx = xc
        besty = yc
        besta = rx
        bestb = ry
        maxarea = rx*ry



print "best iter %s  center %s %s radius %s %s" % (bestiter,bestx,besty,besta,besty)


draw_ellips(ax,bestx,besty,besta,bestb,'red',2) # best ellipse
draw_ellips(ax,xc,yc,rx,ry,'green',3)  # final iter

check_inner(px,py,11.8,4.3,13.6,9.4)
```